# DataGridView - Data added does not stay after closing application

Tags: vb.net

I have created a VB windows form Application with text boxes and a datagridview.

The idea is for the user to enter information onto the text boxes, and then click a button to save to the grid view. This works fine, but when closing the application and reopening the data is gone.

The below code is what i use to save the data to the grid view.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rnum As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    If Me.CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        Clipboard.SetText("Situation:" & vbNewLine & Me.TextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Actions:" & vbNewLine & Me.TextBox2.Text & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Next Steps:" & vbNewLine & Me.TextBox3.Text & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Notes:" & vbNewLine & Me.TextBox4.Text)
    Else
        Clipboard.SetText("Situation:" & vbNewLine & Me.TextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Actions:" & vbNewLine & Me.TextBox2.Text & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Next Steps:" & vbNewLine & Me.TextBox3.Text)
    End If

    DataGridView1.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("Situation").Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
    DataGridView1.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("Actions").Value = Me.TextBox2.Text
    DataGridView1.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("NextSteps").Value = Me.TextBox3.Text
    DataGridView1.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("SupportingDocuments").Value = Me.TextBox4.Text

    MsgBox("Added to Clipboard")

End Sub
```

The application is used by different users on different machine, so i want the gridview to have saved what that individual user has added.

I know im missing something easy, like adding a dataset but wouldnt this have to be on a static location used by everyone? And i also looked into xml files but cannot seem to find what im looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There has to be some sort of storage mechanism in order for you to achieve what you want. As stated in your question, you can make use of xml files.

Comment: Why would you expect the data to still be there?  If you open Excel and enter some data, then close it, would you expect the data to be there when you open Excel again?  I would certainly hope not.  You would need to save that data to a file and then open that file again.  You need to do the same.  The usual option would be to use a database.

Comment: Ok, so what i need is for a file to to be created locally on the users machine. Would XML's be the best route for this? Is there any guides that are best used?

Comment: It depends on your data and what you want.

Comment: There are several databases that are free for the download. Go with a database. What seems like it would work with a file grows into Insert, Update and Delete plus searching the data. All are processes that databases are very good at.

Comment: Its just text data i need. I have tried using a database, but it means everyone needs to connect and use this one database. I need text saved to be specific to the users machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to work around databases, but only seeming to get them static. I worked on using code to create xml files on the user profile, and then loading them.

[This Link helped me alot](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e2e64534-d3af-4129-924d-e2ac10605c77/how-to-show-the-history-of-the-secured-files-in-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to select your database in Project Explorer and navigate to its properties. In its properties, set "Copy to Output folder = Copy if Newer"